# Split files into multiple subfolders and zip each subfolder

Tags: command-line, bash

I am using `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`.

I have created the following script to split files in a folder into different subfolders:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir_size=850
dir_name="images"
n=$((`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l`/$dir_size+1))
for i in `seq 1 $n`;
do
    mkdir -p "$dir_name$i";
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -n $dir_size | xargs -i mv "{}" "$dir_name$i"
done
```

However, I would like to `zip` each subfolder after creation, so that I only get zipped subfolders in my final directory.

Any suggestions how to do this?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: `"$dir_name$i"` is a folder you created. So what prevents you, while in the `do...done` loop, from subsequently zipping the folder?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using `zip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for-loop to get a fixed number of items. `a` will increase with the number of `c` and `b` by every iteration.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -td '' < <( \
    find -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*.zip' -print0 \
)
((${#MAPFILE} == 0)) && exit 1

for ((a=0, b=0, c=850; a<${#MAPFILE[@]}; a+=c, b++)); do
    mkdir images$b && \
    mv -t $_ "${MAPFILE[@]:$a:$c}" && zip -mTr images$b images$b
done
```